Subject: Help Needed: Stuck USDT Transaction on Solana Network and Compromised Wallet
1. Initial Transaction: I attempted to transfer USDT from my Phantom Wallet to Binance in order to subsequently transfer to Revolut. Unfortunately, I mistakenly chose the wrong type of USDT (USDTet instead of the standard USDT), which is not yet supported on Binance. As a result, the funds got stuck in the Solana network.
2. Failed Assistance: I reached out to both Phantom and Binance support, but neither could assist me with retrieving the funds stuck in the Solana network. Binance confirmed that they could not help until the specific USDTet is listed on their platform.
3. Contact with Fake Support: Desperate for a solution, I searched online for Solana support and unfortunately contacted a scammer who posed as a Solana support representative. This scammer convinced me to share my 12-word seed phrase for verification purposes through a fraudulent website.
4. Compromised Wallet: The scammer now has full access to my Phantom wallet. Although there are currently no funds in the wallet, I am extremely concerned about the security of any future transactions or returned funds.
5. Current Status: The funds are still stuck in the Solana network, and I am seeking advice on how to:
1. Retrieve the stuck funds safely.
2. Ensure that the funds, if recovered, are directed to a new, secure wallet that the scammer does not have access to.
What steps can I take to resolve this problem securely?

could you clarify what you mean by funds stuck in the Solana network

I’m voting to close this question because this site is for dev q&a, not wallet support

From what I understood so far, the asset with the issue is USDTet, which is not standard USDT and is not supported by Binance yet.
I believe is would be a viable option to wait until Binance support USDTet, since the token will appear in your Binance account if it was sent correctly.
It's very unlikely the assets will be sent back to the compromised wallet, Binance will be credited to your Binance account when support for USDTet is added.
I recommend staying in close contact with Binance support to inform them of your situation, and keep updated about the status of asset support. They may decide to expedite support for your token based on your circumstances.
In the meantime, I wish you the best of luck with resolving this issue.
